# Volley - Server Error Emulator

Tags: php, android-volley

So essentially i'm following a youtube tutorial and playing around with android studio for the first time.

I am having problems connecting with the database and keep getting the response server error.

I've tried checking the php code on a number of website and they keep saying the code is fine.

Any suggestions?

Register Code:

```
    require_once "connect.php";

    if(!$con){
        echo "Connecting failed";
    }else{
        if($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == "MyTestApp"){
            if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
                if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

                    $name = $_POST['name'];
                    $email = $_POST ['email'];
                    $password = md5($_POST['password']);

                    echo $name;
                } 
                else{
                    echo "missing fields required";
                }
                else{
                    echo "Improper request method";
                }
                else{
                    echo "invalid platform";
                }
            }

?>
```

Connection Code:

```
<?php

    require_once "constants.php";

    $con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    if($con){
        echo "Database connection failed";
    }else{
        echo "Connected!!!";
    }

?>
```

Constants code:

```
<?php 

    define ( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USER', 'id1950281_patrickmcmu11an');
    define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'jordan123');
    define('DB_NAME', 'id1950281_penumbralogin');

 ?>
```

Comment: MD5 is considered broken for security purposes and is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Comment: What is the error? What do the logs tell you?

Comment: $password = string password_hash($_POST['password']);

@AlexHowansky like this?

Comment: @ficuscr Server Error from Volley

Comment: @Patrick that is not really helpful. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php If you think it is the DB connection maybe [check for error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Comment: Depends on your context -- use `password_hash()` when you write the password to the database, and `password_verify()` when you're checking a login attempt against the password that was previously stored.